# Statistical problem - find number of objects (A and B) that are giving measured experimental statistics

Tags: statistics, probability

I am working in mass spectrometry field and doing data processing (currently using python scripts). Recently I came up with a question that I have no idea how to solve. Maybe someone was dealing with similar issues...
To be less specific, I will describe it with analogy of apples. They can be either red or green.
We know that in nature the distribution of apples in a fruit forest is 55% red to 45% green (obtained from "very large" number of apples, giving a ratio of 1.22 red/green).

However, we have a supplier who brings us trucks with unknown number of apples that vary from time to time, but the number of apples in the trucks is more or less same. We are only receiving the red/green ratio value. And that ratio varies from 2.5 (red/green) to 0.5 (red/green) and has known shape (not gaussian, but gaussian-like). Is it possible based on the distribution of ratios to have approximation of number of apples in the trucks (approximation means that answer - there are around 10000 apples +/- 100% is still good)?

Comment: Interesting question, although it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. If the distribution of the ratio depends on the number of apples, then in principal you can infer the number of apples, or more precisely, you can infer a distribution over the number of apples. Whether that can work depends strongly on the problem details; my advice is to just talk about the real things you are working with.